# Android NDK release build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I trying to build my android project in release mode.
Is there any optimization flag(s) I need to set in order to build my project in release mode?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unless you have created the Application.mk or defined your application as debuggable inside the AndroidManifest.xml you don't have to do anything because **by default the application's modules are compiled in *release* mode** by the ndk-build script.

Otherwise, you can use the APP_OPTIM directive inside the Application.mk file:

```
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

From android-ndk-r8d/docs/APPLICATION-MK.html file:

```
APP_OPTIM
    This optional variable can be defined to either 'release' or
    'debug'. This is used to alter the optimization level when
    building your application's modules.

    A 'release' mode is the default, and will generate highly
    optimized binaries. The 'debug' mode will generate un-optimized
    binaries which are much easier to debug.

    Note that if your application is debuggable (i.e. if your manifest
    sets the android:debuggable attribute to "true" in its <application>
    tag), the default will be 'debug' instead of 'release'. This can
    be overridden by setting APP_OPTIM to 'release'.

    Note that it is possible to debug both 'release' and 'debug'
    binaries, but the 'release' builds tend to provide less information
    during debugging sessions: some variables are optimized out and
    can't be inspected, code re-ordering can make stepping through
    the code difficult, stack traces may not be reliable, etc...
```