# NDK build with different mk file for release/debug

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

We have a setup where our Android game contains a few native libraries that get built using ndk-build.

Our project contains the following structure:

```
Root
 |
 |-- jni
      |
      |-- Android.mk   // $include ( lib.mk ) and ( photon/photon.mk)
      |-- lib.mk
      |-- photon
            |
            |----- photon.mk
            |----- debug_android_armeabi.mk
            |----- release_android_armeabi.mk
```

One of the libs that get built (Photon) comes with 2 additional makefiles besides its main one - one for debug and one for release.

My question is - how can i pass this info to ndk-build such that the correct additional mk file will be picked up when building?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably, your `photon.mk` looks like

```
...
ifdef DEBUG
  include debug_android_armeabi.mk
else
  include release_android_armeabi.mk
endif
...
```

This way you can simply use

```
ndk-build DEBUG=1
```

If you want to lean on the `ndk` official features for [release/debug build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564918/android-ndk-release-build), you may prefer

```
...
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
  include debug_android_armeabi.mk
else
  include release_android_armeabi.mk
endif
...
```

Comment: The photon.mk doesn't include anything, that's the problem. I added the include directive.

Comment: You can also lean on the **ndk**, by checking `ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)`. **APP_OPTIM** is normally set or chosen in **Application.mk**, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564918/android-ndk-release-build.